# How to get total number of results in Search API View?

Tags: 7, search, views

How can I get the total number of results on a Search API View that has a limit of 5 results to display?

Some more info:
I have to make a bit more complex search where several attachments are combined on a page as a groups of results. Every group should show just the first 5 results, but also a link "see all XX results". I'm using Search API + Solr, Views with exposed fulltext search.
If I use "Global: Results summary" in header or footer, it will show maximum the limit of 5 as a number.

**edit 1**

Search API Solr returns 'numFound' which is what I need, but how do I use it in Views?

Comment: I don't know if it will work on groups or totals like the Global, but you could look at Views Calc module (https://www.drupal.org/project/views_calc)

Comment: Unfortunately, Views Calc cannot do the job.

Comment: Couldn't this be done with the "Pager" option?

Comment: @Beebee Unfortunately no, as this is already an attachment and it doesn't allow its own pager.

Answer (score 5):

So after a day, here's the result:

As J. Reynolds suggested, I finished up using $view->total_rows, but:

- To populate $views->total_rows, you have to use a pager in your view - that was not an option with the attachments.
- If you don't use a pager, you could force populating $view->total_rows by altering the View query before its execution like this:

```
    function mycustommodule_views_pre_execute(&$view) {
      $view->get_total_rows = TRUE;
    }
```

And after that you have that $view->total_rows!

Answer (score 2):

Try with this type of code. You can select either attachment_before or attachment_after, and if the placement is not to your liking you may alter the views template to suit. I know this works with a normal view and I don't see why it would not work with a Search API result. And I think you can place it in a theme's template.php file if you prefer rather than a module.

```
function MYMODULE_views_post_execute(&$view){
    if ($view->name == "MACHINENAME_OF_VIEW") { // can slso check for display if need be
        $view->attachment_before .= <div class="result">$view->total_rows</div>
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but $view->total_rows appears to be empty :(

Answer (score 1):

By configure  Views Global result summary  in header or Footer, we can display Total number of results.

Search with result summary in Header and pass the ​tokens,

@start -- the initial record number in the set
@end -- the last record number in the set
@total -- the total records in the set
@label -- the human-readable name of the view
@per_page -- the number of items per page
@current_page -- the current page number
@current_record_count -- the current page record count
@page_count -- the total page count